# React Function component setting state variable V/s using local variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a functional component and want to update some state in that component (based on some context API object value i.e. I get via useContext)

Now, I see 2 options;

1. Using local variable
2. Using setState

I just wanted to understand the difference between the 2 ways. Also to add, when using setState, I run into below issue
*Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.*

Just to add, this functional component is a direct child of App component and the context object is updated in another component which is also a direct child of App component.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    let myTitle = "ABC"; //Option 1 to use 'myTitle'
    //const [myTitle, setMyTitle] = useState('ABC'); //Option 2 to use 'myTitle'
    if (someContextApiObj.value === "XYZ") {
        myTitle = "XYZ";
        //setMyTitle("XYZ")
    }

    return (
        <>
            <ChildComponent
                myTitle={myTitle}
            />

        </>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Does the user change the title or do you just evaluate it once on component render? Are you passing any props in?

Comment: yes, so title can get updated based on some link click in other component....i am using context api object to retrieve info from that other component

Comment: Can you modify the code in your question to most accurately reflect how the title is being updated?

Comment: It seems you are wanting to compute a `myTitle` value based on some prop or context value being passed to the component. Storing passed props/context values in local state is generally considered anti-pattern in React. Compute the `myTitle` value and pass it along to the child component.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are wanting to compute a `myTitle` value based on some prop or context value being passed to the component. Storing passed props/context values in local state is generally considered anti-pattern in React. Compute the `myTitle` value and pass it along to the child component.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const myTitle = someContextApiObj.value === "XYZ" ? "XYZ" : "ABC";

  return <ChildComponent myTitle={myTitle} />;
};
```

If the `myTitle` value is an expensive calculation or you just want to provide a stable reference to children, use the `useMemo` hook to provide this.

[useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const myTitle = useMemo(() => {
    return someContextApiObj.value === "XYZ" ? "XYZ" : "ABC";
  }, [someContextApiObj]);

  return <ChildComponent myTitle={myTitle} />;
};
```

Comment: So, in this case, it cannot be considered that we are storing the passed props/context values in local state directly, but instead, since it is computed and stored indirectly, we are not violating the pattern...Also assume myTitle would get automatically recomputed every time someContextApiObj.value changes ?

Comment: @copenndthagen Correct. (1) It extends from #3 from [Step 3: Identify the minimal representation of UI state](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state) - "Can you compute it based on any other state or props in your component? If so, it isn't state." Storing the derived "state" in *state* would necessitate an additional lifecycle method (e.g. `useEffect`) to synchronize the local state with changes in props values, which is unnecessary.

Comment: @copenndthagen (2) That said though, *sometimes* the computation may be expensive and/or you *don't* want to recompute the derived "state" each time the component renders. You *could* use the `useState`/`useEffect` couplet.... but that is basically what you get with the `useMemo` that provides a stable, memoized value that only recomputes when a dependency changes. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs into an infinite loop because of your if-clause. If you set the title and the condition doesn't change, it will get set on every rerender causing a new render - infinite chain of rerenders.

Using a state offers you the ability to change the value conditionally, while using a local variable not coupled to a state makes the variable constant.

Comment: Thanks...so is it fine to use a local variable in this case (and get the updated myTitle in the JSX) ....Also if I want to use setState, do you mean, I need to remove the if condition and figure out a way to setState directly?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Hook [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [myTitle, setMyTitle] = useState('ABC'); //Option 2 to use 'myTitle'

    useEffect(()=> {
        if (someContextApiObj.value === "XYZ") {
            setMyTitle("XYZ")
        }
    }, []);
    

    return (
        <>
            <ChildComponent
                myTitle={myTitle}
            />

        </>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks...I think this solution seems good...is it fine to have the useEffect have a dependency of context obj ...i.e useEffect(()=> {

    }, [someContextApiObj]);